# PHP Request for Grafana API Returning Error

Tags: php, api, grafana

I am making a request for api chart to be automatically redirected, without password, after redirection, receive the following alert:

[image]

**SCRIPT**

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "3000",
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:3000/d/BSFmuV5Zz/dash?orgId=1",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer api-key-here"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) { 
  echo "CURL Error #:" . $err; ?>      
<?php } else {
  echo $response;
}

?>
```

**Operating System:** Windows

**Download Link:** https://grafana.com/grafana/download?platform=windows

Comment: It looks like you're calling the regular dashboard path, which serves the html needed to bootstrap the Grafana javascript application.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to display the chart dashboard without prompting username and password